# how to search specific characters in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

I need to find an instance in a wordpress plugin where they use the term "EMail" but when i do a but when i do a shift, command, F search I and enter in that text it finds all instances of the word "email".  is there a way in Sublime text 3 to search for the specific characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable case sensitive search.